# Работа с word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class Init {

public static void main ( String[] argc ) throws IOException {
    HWPFDocument myWorkBook = new HWPFDocument(
            new POIFSFileSystem(
                    new FileInputStream("/home/jashka/Лаби/6.docx")));

    System.out.println(myWorkBook.getDocumentSummaryInformation());

   }

}
```

Ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException:
> The supplied data appears to be in the
> Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the
> part of POI that deals with OLE2
> Office Documents. You need to call a
> different part of POI to process this
> data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

Гугление не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы открыть docx используйте `XWPFDocument`:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class Init {

    public static void main ( String[] argc ) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("/home/jashka/Лаби/6.docx"));
        ...
}
```

Дальше из этого объекта можно всё достать или изменить.